# Catch continuous pressing of the NFC card to NFC reader ("LongPress")

Tags: android, events, android-intent, tags, nfc

This is how usually an NFC tag is detected in my app:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {      
    if (intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)) {
        Tag nfcTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        ...
    }
}
```

Now I need to also listen if an NFC tag is held close to the reader for a long time (about 3 seconds). In that case I want to do something else (similar to distinguishing between a normal press and a longpress on a view). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The method

> isConnected()

tells you whether the connection to the tag ist still alive. If you check the connection periodically, you can detect a long connection.

Comment: is it Ndef isConnected() method? but my cards doesn't have anything besides nfc ID, therefore Ndef is always null

Comment: You may try: 
`nfcTag.connect();
boolean connected = nfcTag.isConnected();
nfcTag.close();`

Answer (score 0):

The concept behind NFC is to quickly exchange small amounts of data between a tag and an NFC device (or two NFC devices) and not to detect the duration of an interaction. Consequently, there is no dedicated event that lets you distinguish between short and slightly longer interactions.

As [corvairjo wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38321778/2425802), you could connect to the tag and check if the tag is still connected after a certain amount of time (e.g. 3 seconds). However, you can only measure the time from the point where your app is notified about the tag (i.e. after `onNewIntent()` was invoked). You can't measure the time that Android needed to notify your app after the user actually scanned the tag.

Note that `isConnected()` on its own is not reliable for all device/tag combinations. The most reliable way to test if a tag is still present would be to send a valid command to the tag and check if you get a response:

```
new AsyncTask<Tag, Void, Boolean>() {
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Tag... tags) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            // test if tag is still connected
            Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tags[0]);
            if (ndef != null) {
                try {
                    ndef.connect();
                    ndef.getNdefMessage();
                } finally {
                    ndef.close();
                }
                return Boolean.TRUE;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (result) {
            // "long press" event
        }
    }
}.execute(tag);
```

If your tag supports NDEF (the `Ndef` tag technology) you could simply query the tag for its NDEF message using `Ndef.getNdefMessage()` (see above). If your tag does not support NDEF, you would first need to find out what commands your tag supports and then send such a command using the proper tag technology.

E.g. if your tag is an MIFARE Ultralight or NTAG tag (or any NFC Forum Type 2 tag), you could use:

```
// test if tag is still connected
NfcA nfca = NfcA.get(tags[0]);
if (nfca != null) {
    try {
        nfca.connect();
        byte[] response = nfca.transceive(new byte[] { (byte)0x30, (byte)0x00 });
        if ((response != null) && (response.length > 0))
            return Boolean.TRUE;
        }
    } finally {
        ndef.close();
    }
}
```